# table post_post has no column named publishing_date

Tags: python, django, web, pycharm

im just a beginner in web coding and i got this error while i was adding my first app to the my first website i couldn't find a solution to this i thought it was something related to language of my website but it didn't worked and here is my codes that i just wrote like i said i just started to coding so i dont know anything to solve this issue
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7HO8.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lbER.png)

Answer (score 0):

These are not strictly errors, but warnings that relate to Python `PEP 8` coding rules.

If it's strictly a table error, try the following commands before starting the server.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```